# Can't deploy a project to heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, create-react-app

I was trying to deploy my project to heroku but couldn't do it cause I got application error. I checked the logs and what i got. I already two times created a new project and deploying its to heroku but it had no effect
My logs:

```
2020-03-24T15:42:17.850087+00:00 app[api]: Release v2 created by user melnicukboris@gmail.com
2020-03-24T15:42:17.850087+00:00 app[api]: Enable Logplex by user melnicukboris@gmail.com
2020-03-24T15:42:17.619338+00:00 app[api]: Release v1 created by user melnicukboris@gmail.com
2020-03-24T15:42:17.619338+00:00 app[api]: Initial release by user melnicukboris@gmail.com
2020-03-24T15:48:41.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user melnicukboris@gmail.com
2020-03-24T15:50:18.725239+00:00 app[api]: Scaled to web@1:Free by user melnicukboris@gmail.com
2020-03-24T15:50:18.704621+00:00 app[api]: Release v3 created by user melnicukboris@gmail.com
2020-03-24T15:50:18.704621+00:00 app[api]: Deploy befed784 by user melnicukboris@gmail.com
2020-03-24T15:50:25.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-03-24T15:50:31.090135+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-03-24T15:50:34.343645+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-24T15:50:34.343668+00:00 app[web.1]: > heroku@0.1.0 start /app
2020-03-24T15:50:34.343668+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-03-24T15:50:34.343668+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-24T15:50:38.383048+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.19.89.142/
2020-03-24T15:50:38.383799+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-03-24T15:50:38.383980+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-03-24T15:50:38.384112+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-03-24T15:50:38.388825+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-03-24T15:50:38.388827+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-24T15:50:38.609712+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-24T15:50:38.615793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-03-24T15:50:38.592130+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-03-24T15:50:45.914934+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-03-24T15:50:48.196103+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-24T15:50:48.196153+00:00 app[web.1]: > heroku@0.1.0 start /app
2020-03-24T15:50:48.196154+00:00 app[web.1]: > react-scripts start
2020-03-24T15:50:48.196155+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-03-24T15:50:50.107577+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://172.18.177.26/
2020-03-24T15:50:50.107952+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from
2020-03-24T15:50:50.108048+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /app/public
2020-03-24T15:50:50.108113+00:00 app[web.1]: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
2020-03-24T15:50:50.108298+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development server...
2020-03-24T15:50:50.108298+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-03-24T15:50:50.249772+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-03-24T15:50:50.233637+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2020-03-24T15:50:50.827613+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mysterious-forest-69349.herokuapp.com request_id=a1dd32c7-edc8-4cb7-b4e9-c2a0f0b7d15c fwd="109.229.30.180" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-24T15:50:51.173161+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mysterious-forest-69349.herokuapp.com request_id=1446b81a-4758-4493-b409-9354e3fbfaf4 fwd="109.229.30.180" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-24T15:56:14.859311+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mysterious-forest-69349.herokuapp.com request_id=65f6625a-0b18-4aff-ae02-97227d5438b8 fwd="109.229.30.180" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-03-24T15:56:15.131704+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=mysterious-forest-69349.herokuapp.com request_id=532be6ff-69df-44fc-beb5-b1e9ef29932f fwd="109.229.30.180" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I did heroku run rails console but it didn't help

Comment: show the code where you are running the web server. The port is missing from your log.

Comment: I do it without any webser just with create-react-app. I deployed it by tutorial on youtube and that was alright

Comment: You should definitely be using a web server. This is a problem: "Starting the development server". Don't use the development server in production.

Comment: Im having the exact same issue.  Was this solved?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the cause

> 2020-03-24T15:50:50.108298+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the development
>   server...

react-scripts start will start a development server. Try to use this buildpack instead
[Heroku Buildpack for create-react-app](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack)

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this!

[create-react-app-buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/mars/create-react-app-buildpack)